# How to convert French, German Prices to Double Value in java

Tags: java

I have French price like : 2 44 455,00.... I am using below code to convert it into double.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
String s = "2 44 455,00";
double d = nf.parse(s);
```

The output i am getting is only "2"

How to get correct value

Note : I don't want to user replaceAll() method of String, because different prices will be in different format

Comment: Have you tried stripping spaces before conversion?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output :244455.00

Comment: what other formats can there be?

Comment: German : 2.333,00 like this other formats there

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove spaces in your String :

```
s=s.replace(" ","");
```

then parse.

Comment: Those spaces might be non-breaking spaces, so `\u00a0` might be required, or even better: `\\s`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to strip the spaces then apply below code:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    String s1 = "2 44 455,80";
    String s2 = s1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    double d = (Double) nf.parse(s2);
    System.out.println(d);
```

When you put `00` after `,` it treats it as Long instead Double.

Comment: I don't want to user replaceAll() method of String, because different prices will be in different format. For German it is like 2.333.00 . Again i need to use replaceAll()